# Python: How to filter a Pandas DataFrame using Values from a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, series

**Context**

I am currently processing some data and encountered a problem.
I would like to filter a Pandas DataFrame using Values from a Series.
However, this always throws the following Error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

**Code**

```py
# DataFrame
userID (Int) | startTS (Int) | endTS (Int) | placeID (String)

# Group Data into Subgroups, one for each User.
stayGroup = stayData.groupby('userID')

for userID, data in stayGroup:

    for index, row in data.iterrows():

        # Stays starting during this Stay.
        staysA = data[row['startTS'] < data['startTS'] < row['endTS']]

        # Stays ending during this Stay.
        staysB = data[row['startTS'] < data['endTS'] < row['endTS']]

        # Stays starting before and ending after this Stay.
        staysC = data[(row['startTS'] >= data['startTS']) & (row['endTS'] <= data['endTS'])]
```

**Question**

Does anyone have an idea what's this error means and how I can solve it?
Thanks a lot for your assistance in advance!

Comment: you must provide a minimal example of a DataFrame, explain the logic, and provide the matching expected output

Comment: I think we can do this more efficiently than looping, as @mozway request, provide a dataframe and expected output.  We can help you optimize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `row['startTS'] < data['startTS'] < row['endTS']`, you can use

```py
data['startTS'].between(row['startTS'], row['endTS'], inclusive='neither')
# or
(row['startTS'] < data['startTS']) & (df['startTS'] < row['endTS'])
```